# How to let `dpkg -i` install dependencies for me?

Tags: dpkg

Say, I have `foo-1.2.3.deb` which depends on `perl` and `python`, however, running command:

```
dpkg -i ./foo-1.2.3.deb
```

won't install these dependencies. So I must `apt-get install perl python` by hand.

How to make `dpkg -i` install these dependencies for me automatically?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to automatically fetch missing dependencies when installing software from .deb?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/58202/how-to-automatically-fetch-missing-dependencies-when-installing-software-from-d)

Comment: @pd12: Hooray for circular references! :-D

Comment: heh, I decided to link both and see which one the mods would select.

Comment: It's amazing that in 2016, a [.deb graphical installation still fails silently without telling the user anything about missing dependencies](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/264258967/Installation%20of%20.deb%20fails%20silently.gif).

Comment: _“Is it because I write `sudo apt install pkg` into a bash script and didn't execute the script with `sudo`?”_ This depends on whether you entered the password or configured your OS to not require the password for the script. Anyway, have you captured the output of the script?

Comment: @Melebius The output looks like normal. It asks me to type password when I execute it. After typing the password, all of `sudo apt install` in the script will be executed without any error.

Comment: For the first paragraph, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/794983/where-are-packages-stored-installed-with-apt-in-ubuntu-16-04, for the rest of the question, you'd be better off with a solution from https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline

Comment: I guess all answers depend on the repo for your OS version actually having the unmet dependencies, which mine doesn't.

Answer (score 718, accepted):

After using `dpkg`, running the following command helped me to install the required dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

In all, your terminal should look like this:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i package_with_unsatisfied_dependencies.deb
dpkg: dependency problems prevent ... 
[additional messages]

$ sudo apt-get -f install
[apt messages]
Setting up [dependency]...
Setting up package_with_unsatisfied_dependencies...
```

**Notice** the line about `Setting up package_with_unsatisfied_dependencies`. This [fixes](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/apt-get) (and completes) the installation of `package_with_unsatisfied_dependencies.deb`.

Comment: Should I run `sudo dpkg -i mypackage.deb` again ?

Comment: After running `sudo apt-get -f install` my package and it's dependencies were all installed. Running `sudo dpkg -i my_package.deb` is unnecessary and will just install the package again.

Comment: Following works on Ubuntu 14.04: `sudo dpkg -i package.deb; sudo apt-get -f install; sudo dpkg -i package.deb`. The first `dpkg -i` run marks dependencies, `apt-get -f install` installs required dependencies and the second `dpkg -i`successfully installs the package. Note that `apt-get install -f` is totally different command.

Comment: @ysth no, do not do `dpkg -i --force`; that will force-install a broken package!  Running `dpkg` /without/ `--force` will make the necessary entry in the package database so that `apt-get -f install` will do the right thing.

Comment: @Lotharyx: I can't try it right now, but I didn't think the dpkg without force (that fails due to missing dependencies) would make an entry in the package database

Comment: @ysth It does.  I did try it.  YMMV.

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen are really `apt-get -f install` and `apt-get install -f` different? [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/381145/what-was-the-difference-between-sudo-apt-get-f-install-and-sudo-apt-get-inst) it's said they're the same.

Comment: what if I don't have `apt-get` installed ? I need to solve dependencies solely on dpkg

Comment: `-f` stands for `--fix-broken`.

Comment: This solution isn't working for me since it also automatically install the most recent version of the package, hence instead of having foo-1.2.3 I end up having foo-2.0.0 and it's not what I was looking for.

Answer (score 264):

starting with apt 1.1 (available in Xenial (16.04), stretch) `apt install` also allows local files:

```
sudo apt install ./foo-1.2.3.deb
```

So much simpler and cleaner.

See the [release announcment](https://mvogt.wordpress.com/2015/11/30/apt-1-1-released/)

Comment: for unmet dependencies, use `--fix-broken` as indicated by apt

Comment: sudo apt -f install ./foo-1.2.3.deb`

Answer (score 121):

You can install `gdebi-core`, which is the command line version of the GDebi package installer from 10.04 and earlier. In the newer versions of Ubuntu, the Software Center is used to install debs, which doesn't have a command line equivalent.

To install a deb package using gdebi, just run:

```
sudo gdebi my_package_1.0.deb
```

Comment: Probably one of the best answers here.

Comment: there is `mk-build-deps` as well if you got `debian/control` file

Answer (score 44):

## [Gdebi](http://packages.ubuntu.com/gdebi)

`gdebi` installs a deb package and its dependencies. To use it run:

```
sudo gdebi package.deb
```

In newer versions of Ubuntu, this is not installed by default, so you will need to install it from the repositories.

See [`man gdebi`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/gdebi) for a full list of options.

`gdebi` is the command line equivalent to the graphical tool of the same name that used to be included by default in Ubuntu. The command for the graphical tool is `gdebi-gtk` and has similar functionality:

[image: gdebi-gtk]

Comment: gdebi-gtk wont show required deps (the version I have here at least, and it looks like a bug), but the command line will! If we have another machine with the packages we can use `dpkg-repack` on it based on such deps list :)

Answer (score 22):

running

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

after installing package with dpkg may solve broken depencies (at least man apt-get  say so...). Ill update when i will check it.

Comment: Should I run `sudo dpkg -i mypackage.deb` again ?

Comment: `apt-get -f install` works, but `apt-get install -f` is not the same.

Answer (score 17):

If you need to run a command that automatically resolves all of a .deb file's dependencies and installs the .deb file and its missing dependencies with the same command, you will need to update your installed software with `sudo apt update`. Then open the terminal, change directories using `cd` to the directory containing package-name.deb, and type:

```
apt install --simulate ./package-name.deb # This command does not require sudo.
```

where `package-name.deb` should be replaced by the name of a .deb file located in the current directory that you are trying to install.

The above command will not install anything, but it will print a message listing any dependencies of package-name.deb that do not exist in the default Ubuntu repositories. You will need to manually download and install the .deb files of these missing dependency packages in order to install package-name.deb. Run `apt install --simulate ./manually-downloaded-package.deb` before installing any of these manually downloaded dependency packages in order to check if these packages have any unmet dependencies themselves.

If the simulated command completes successfully, run the following command to install package-name.deb.

```
sudo apt install ./package-name.deb
```

There can be multiple .deb files in the same command if the .deb files are all located in the current directory.

```
sudo apt install ./package-name-1.deb ./package-name-2.deb
```

Answer (score 11):

dpkg doesn't have dependency support. There is a way around it but that would require you to make a local database (and thus you would already know the dependencies) and it is considered obsolete (...).

Does it have to be command line? (server install?) If so also have a look at `apt-get -f` but be careful: solving dependencies after install could have you end up with a broken system.

[gdebi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GDebi) (gui frontend) used to be able to do this but got replaced with USC.

How did you download the .deb. Some of the new 11.04 features is the handling of .deb downloaded from a website: it gets opend in USC so dependencies will be solved by the installer.

EDIT based on comment by andrew:
**`sudo gdebi foo-1.2.3.deb`** 
would do the trick!!

Comment: gdebi can still be used for this. Software Center is now just the default app. Also, as Chen Xiao-Long notes, gdebi can also be used on the command line.

Comment: cool! then the question has an answer because gdebi can be used on commandline too it seems.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

You could create a file `dpkg-dep-inst` with the following content.

```
#!/bin/bash

DEBIAN_FILE1=$1
dpkg -i $DEBIAN_FILE1 || apt-get --fix-broken install
```

I assume you created the file in your home folder. Make it executable with `chmod +x dpkg-dep-inst` and move it to `/usr/local/bin` with `sudo cp dpkg-dep-inst /usr/local/bin`.

Now you can install the debian package with dependencies automatically with:

```
sudo dpkg-dep-inst foo-1.2.3.deb
```

Comment: Use `apt-get --yes --fix-broken install` and make the fixing automatic.

Comment: @ysth No, not in general.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to `gdebi-gtk` you can use Ubuntu Software Center.

Double click on the package and an install button should be available.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this problem. Calling `apt-get install -f` will **not** install *recommended* dependencies, though! The only workaround for this would be then to create a local repository and add to `/etc/apt/sources.list`, i.e.:

```
apt-ftparchive packages . > Packages && gzip < Packages > Packages.gz
sudo echo "deb file://$PWD /" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-get update
```

Answer (score 2):

The below command will attempt to correct any dependency issues

`sudo apt-get install -f`

So it's good practice to run that after installing a package

`sudo dpkg -i YOUR-PACKAGE.deb && sudo apt-get install -f`

Answer (score 1):

Actually the answer is that `dpkg` package manager cannot install dependencies out of the box. You cam `man dpkg` and found that out. So you need to use tools like `apt`, `apt-get`, `aptitude`, ..., based on `dpkg`.

I would say just the same case is for the `rpm` package manager on the other Linux hemisphere. `rmp` is not meant to do dependency based installs. It can install single packages, and for installing the dependencies you use `yum`, `urpmi`, `up2date` these are all based on RPM.

As noted there is a slight danger installing packages with `dpkg` directly, because later dependency resolution resolving may end up with a broken system as @Rinzwind outlined.