# What can I use to install a package file with dependency from command line?

Tags: command-line, dpkg

I want to install my project's debian package from a shell script.

For that I'm using the command `sudo dpkg -i my_project_0.1.deb`. But it's not going to install dependency.

I've also tried `sudo dpkg -i --force-depends`. But still error.

Below commands can solve the problem,

```
sudo dpkg -i downloaded_package.deb
sudo apt-get -f install
```

but I'm looking for any other solution (as it would install broken dependency for all packages).

How could I solve the problem? Is there any other command instead of dpkg?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `aptitude` as in `sudo aptitude install downloaded_package.deb`?

Comment: as per your suggestion, I have tried `sudo aptitude install downloaded_package.deb` 
and it gives an error :
**"Couldn't find any package whose name or description matched my_project.deb"**

Comment: Do you provide the correct path in the command?

Comment: Yes, but may be because, my package is not registered 
as when I've tried `sudo aptitude install python-lxml` (where python-lxml is registered package on ubuntu archive) It works.

Comment: @N.N. `aptitude` cannot take a filename as a parameter, for what I know.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to let `dpkg -i` install dependencies for me?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/40011/how-to-let-dpkg-i-install-dependencies-for-me)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `gdebi` (package `gdebi-core` if it's not installed)