# What was the difference between `sudo apt-get -f install` and `sudo apt-get install -f`?

Tags: command-line

What was the difference between `sudo apt-get -f install` and `sudo apt-get install -f` commands?
 I had seen these two commands large number of times,is there any `differences in functionality` of these two commands?

Comment: No, it's the same ASAIK

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They are the same.

apt-get and install are obligatory. The -f is optional and can be placed anywhere after apt-get. Though the man page has them explained as apt-get -f install:

```
   apt-get [-asqdyfmubV] [-o=config_string] [-c=config_file]
           [-t=target_release] [-a=architecture] {update | upgrade |
           dselect-upgrade | dist-upgrade |
           install pkg [{=pkg_version_number | /target_release}]...  |
           remove pkg...  | purge pkg...  |
           source pkg [{=pkg_version_number | /target_release}]...  |
           build-dep pkg [{=pkg_version_number | /target_release}]...  |
           download pkg [{=pkg_version_number | /target_release}]...  |
           check | clean | autoclean | autoremove | {-v | --version} |
           {-h | --help}}
```