# Get kdenlive 0.9.4 on ubuntu 14.10

Tags: 14.10, versions, kdenlive

I am wondering if it is possible to get an old version of software for Ubuntu.

I want to get `kdenlive 0.9.4` for Ubuntu 14.10 and is there a way to do so ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search find packages in [Ubuntu Package Search](http://packages.ubuntu.com) - in this case [the results for kdenlive](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=kdenlive&searchon=names) show:

- [kdenlive 0.9.4](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/kdenlive) from the Raring (13.04 unsupported version).
- It also needs [kdenlive-data 0.9.4](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/kdenlive-data) to work.
- It may also need [libmlt5](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/libmlt5), as well as some other packages [listed as dependencies](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/kdenlive#pdeps) (packages required for kdenlive to work) that aren't available in Utopic.

You can download the packages from the bottom of the packages' page *(see also [How do I check if I have a 32-bit or a 64-bit OS?](https://askubuntu.com/q/41332/178596), you probably need to know which to pick)*.
Then, making sure Utopic's kdenlive *(and it unneeded dependencies, use `apt-get`'s `autoremove`)* has been removed, install the packages [using gdebi](https://askubuntu.com/q/40011/178596) or by opening them from File Manager.

If the packages do not work as they unsolvable dependences for that version (the dependency is installed but the wrong version), you may be able to get old versions of [the source code](https://kdenlive.org/download-source) and compile from them

Note that if you want to try a newer version of Kdenlive (0.9.10), you can use [it's PPA](https://launchpad.net/~sunab/+archive/ubuntu/kdenlive-release) ([source](https://kdenlive.org/download-ubuntu))

Comment: Oh, and try not to end up in a '[dependency hell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_hell)' :D