# How To Install Remarkable editor On Ubuntu from terminal

Tags: 14.04, editor

How should I install the [Remarkable editor](http://remarkableapp.github.io/) on Ubuntu 14.04 in a terminal session?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Open the terminal and type :

```
wget https://remarkableapp.github.io/files/remarkable_1.62_all.deb
```

And :

```
sudo gdebi remarkable_1.62_all.deb
```

if you get error like `gdebi: commande not found` you can install it by typing :

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi-core
```

Comment: `gdebi` ? Why don't you use the standard `dpkg -i` to install a debian package?

Comment: @darksky `gdebi` automatically gets missing dependancies, take a look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/40011/how-to-let-dpkg-i-install-dependencies-for-me)

Comment: I'm back after few years, if anyone runs into `Dependency is not satisfiable: gir1.2-webkit-3.0` error on Ubuntu 20.04, download fixed deb from [here](https://github.com/seiferteric/remarkable_debfix)

Comment: This solution combined with last comment from **Bilal** above `Dependency is not satisfiable: gir1.2-webkit-3.0` worked on Ubuntu 22.04 with Remarkable 1.87 `.deb` package.

Answer (score 5):

you just have to do :

```
wget https://remarkableapp.github.io/files/remarkable_1.62_all.deb
dpkg -i remarkable_1.62_all.deb
```

then (to add missing dependencies) :

```
apt-get upgrade -f
```

and the retry install :

```
dpkg -i remarkable_1.62_all.deb
```

Comment: This is, without doubt, the correct way to do it.