# Unable to install wk .deb

Tags: 14.04, dpkg, wkhtmltopdf

I am unable to install wkhtmltopdf on Ubuntu 14.4. I downloaded from [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html) Linux (Ubuntu Trusty) 64 bit.
I ran the following command:

```
sudo dpkg -i wkhtmltox-0.12.2.1_linux-trusty-amd64.deb
```

Here's the log

```
(Reading database ... 61662 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack wkhtmltox-0.12.2.1_linux-trusty-amd64.deb ...
Unpacking wkhtmltox (0.12.2.1) over (0.12.2.1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of wkhtmltox:
 wkhtmltox depends on fontconfig; however:
  Package fontconfig is not installed.
 wkhtmltox depends on libjpeg-turbo8; however:
  Package libjpeg-turbo8 is not installed.
 wkhtmltox depends on xfonts-base; however:
  Package xfonts-base is not installed.
 wkhtmltox depends on xfonts-75dpi; however:
  Package xfonts-75dpi is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package wkhtmltox (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 wkhtmltox
```

I searched but could not find anything specific. What am I missing here?

Comment: Do you really need 0.12.2? I ask because wkhtmltopdf 0.9.9 is already in the ubuntu repo for trusty: http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/wkhtmltopdf

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/40011/how-to-let-dpkg-i-install-dependencies-for-me on how to install dependencies.

Comment: Yes i need the latest version

Comment: @rinzwind will try that

Comment: @user1629362 alternative: download the DEBs it complains about and "dpkg" those 1st (dpkg does not solve dependencies for you).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

first of all, if you don't care about version, you can install the package founded in the official Ubuntu repos:

```
sudo apt-get install wkhtmltopdf
```

But if you want to install your specific version above(0.12.2) you should resolve the package dependencies.

first try to run the command:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

If this solves it then ok else you  have to install each dependency yourself.

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of wkhtmltox:
 wkhtmltox depends on fontconfig; however:
  Package fontconfig is not installed.
 wkhtmltox depends on libjpeg-turbo8; however:
  Package libjpeg-turbo8 is not installed.
 wkhtmltox depends on xfonts-base; however:
  Package xfonts-base is not installed.
 wkhtmltox depends on xfonts-75dpi; however:
  Package xfonts-75dpi is not installed.
```

From above you can install each dependency yourself

```
sudo apt-get install fontconfig
sudo apt-get install libjpeg-turbo8
sudo apt-get install xfonts-base
sudo apt-get install xfonts-75dpi
```

**But** an easier solution is to use [gdebi](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/gdebi/).

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi
```

then you can use it to resolve dependencies:

```
sudo gdebi wkhtmltox-0.12.2.1_linux-trusty-amd64.deb
```

Comment: Where is it installed then?
-bash: /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf: No such file or directory

Comment: Got it: /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf 
and: /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltoimage