# Where are packages stored installed with APT in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: apt, package-management

I know that packages installed with **`apt-get`** are stored in `/var/cache/apt/archives`. 
I just installed mariadb server in Ubuntu 16.04 with following command:

```
sudo apt install mariadb-server
```

When I tried to find packages in `/var/cache/apt/archives`, there are no packages. Where are they stored if it's not in this directory?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you use `apt` instead of `apt-get`, the default is **not** to store debs anywhere if the apt install is successful.

From `/usr/share/doc/apt/NEWS.Debian.gz`:

> apt (1.2~exp1) experimental; urgency=medium
>
> [ Automatic removal of debs after install ]
>     After packages are successfully installed by `apt(8)`,
>     the corresponding `.deb` package files will be
>     removed from the `/var/cache/apt/archives` cache directory.
>
> This can be changed by setting the apt configuration option
>       `Binary::apt::APT::Keep-Downloaded-Packages` to `true`. E.g:
>
> ```
> # echo 'Binary::apt::APT::Keep-Downloaded-Packages "true";' \
> > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01keep-debs
> ```
>
> Please note that the behavior of apt-get is unchanged. The
>     downloaded debs will be kept in the cache directory after they
>     are installed. To enable the behavior for other tools, you can set
>     `APT::Keep-Downloaded-Packages` to `false`.

Comment: Ok. Got it. So this is also a difference between **apt** and **apt-get**.