# Does apt have a directory where it stores all downloads?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, apt, aptitude

I was wondering if apt has a directory where it stores all downloaded deb files through it. Any insight?

Comment: Note, for 16.04: https://askubuntu.com/questions/794983/where-are-packages-stored-installed-with-apt-in-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: Added that link into my answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, there is such directory. That's `/var/cache/apt/archives/`

Note that there is a subtle difference between `apt` and `apt-get` in the fact that `apt` doesn't cache packages by default in 16.04. This can be amended by setting `Binary::apt::APT::Keep-Downloaded-Packages` to `true` in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01keep-debs` file. As root user , do:

```
echo 'Binary::apt::APT::Keep-Downloaded-Packages "true";' > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01keep-debs
```

[See also](https://askubuntu.com/a/794987/295286).