# What is the difference between these two commands?

Tags: 14.04, apt, sudo

What is the difference between the command line `sudo apt-get update` and the command line `sudo apt update`?

Although I've been using only Ubuntu and Ubuntu-based distros in the last several years, I still consider myself an entry-level user when it comes about command lines and Terminal-related stuff. I mention this aspect because I need a novice-friendly explanation.

A bit of background info: on a regular basis I run the commands `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` in my Terminal. And I also know that it is recommended to do so before installing any app, in order to avoid any errors.

But today I have decided to [install snapd on my Ubuntu 14.04 system](https://docs.snapcraft.io/core/install-ubuntu), and I noticed that, on their webpage there are mentioned these two lines:

`sudo apt update
sudo apt install snapd`

And this is why I am puzzled. (By the way, these lines work fine in my case.)

Comment: @pomsky - I mean exactly the difference between "sudo apt-get update" and "sudo apt update".

Comment: Link given by DK Bose got you covered. "apt" is a newer frontend to the debian APT tools than apt-get. You will not have apt available in 14.04

Comment: `apt` is there in 14.04 as well: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/apt.8.html but I don't know if it has the features available in later versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: run it and see.  for the most part it's the same, but with pretty colors & for some functions a cute status graph, but it's still missing some functionality, and until it has all functionality included, you'll still have the old `apt-get` installed for when you need those features. `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` is now `sudo apt full-upgrade`, but dist-upgrade still works in `apt` (even if not in `man apt`; maybe it'll go when `apt-get` is finally depreciated? (*if that ever happens*))

Comment: But see https://askubuntu.com/a/926850/248158 because, by default, `apt install` doesn't retain debs in `/var/cache/apt` whereas `apt-get install` does by default.

Comment: @pomsky - Yes, I did. Thank you for the correction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apt is the new frontend. More specifically apt offers the same more-or-less functionalities as apt-get, apt-cache etc in a single command. You can read more about the differencies and similarities here: https://itsfoss.com/apt-vs-apt-get-difference/

Comment: Thank you! The information from the link you provided explains things in a more clear way that the information I got from the other links (including the other AU similar question). It is exactly like I asked: novice-friendly.