# How can I prevent automatic deletions in /var/cache/apt/archives?

Tags: apt, package-management

Many people seem to want to keep /var/cache/apt/archives as empty as possible automatically.  Unsurprisingly, there is plenty of information out there about how to accomplish that goal.

My question is just the opposite: How can I prevent anything/everything from being deleted from that directory automatically?

If you can't answer the above question, then maybe you can answer this question: "What process(es) is/are emptying that directory, when, and on account of what system configuration specification(s)?"

(These days I'm running both 16.04 and 18.04 servers.)

Comment: Also [Where are packages stored installed with APT in Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/794983/where-are-packages-stored-installed-with-apt-in-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: Ravexina was right, I hope: # echo 'Binary::apt::APT::Keep-Downloaded-Packages "true";' > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01keep-debs