# How to force caching apt-installed packages so that I can copy and install on another machine?

Tags: apt, package-management

I want to force caching the installed packages with `apt-get install (apt install)` in `/var/cache/apt`. Currently, I found some of them are cached, but most of them are not. I want to cache all of them to install them on another machine by copying these packages without downloading them again from the Internet, especially for large packages which cost a lot of time.

Comment: Possible:  [How to create a local APT repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/170348/how-to-create-a-local-apt-repository) or [How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline)

Comment: The `apt` command doesn't cache the deb files by default, but the `apt-get` command does, so use `apt-get` and only `apt-get` if you want everything to be cached, or change the config as shown in https://askubuntu.com/a/794987/158442

Answer (score 1):

I think that setting up your local machine as a repository would be a better option, but if you want to just download a package you can run:

```bsh
sudo apt install -d package
```

If you want to cache all of your installed packages you can run

```bsh
sudo apt install -d $(apt list --installed | cut -d'/' -f 1 | grep -v "Listing..." | tr '\n' ' ')
```