# installing chrome in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apt, 16.04, software-installation, google-chrome

Im running 64 bits version, Im very new to ubuntu, just dived into it. this is what I do:

```
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

then get:

```
`2016-10-01 23:22:41 (1.30 MB/s) - ‘google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb’ saved [49990192/49990192]`
```

then

```
sudo dpkg –I google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

and get:

```
dpkg: error: need an action option
```

Type

```
dpkg --help for help about installing and deinstalling packages [*];

Use 'apt' or 'aptitude' for user-friendly package management;
```

Type

```
dpkg -Dhelp for a list of dpkg debug flag values;
```

Type

```
dpkg --force-help for a list of forcing options;
```

Type

```
dpkg-deb --help for help about manipulating *.deb files;
```

Options marked [*] produce a lot of output - pipe it through 'less' or 'more' !
Thanks in advance and sorry for my idiocy too

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You typed the wrong command to install the application.  You used an uppercase `I` when it should have been a lower case `i`.  Unlike Windows, the case of the letters in a command makes a difference.

Run this to install the package:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

**Just change your Uppercase `I` to the lowercase `i` in the command you typed** and you'll be all set.

By the way, the difference between the lower case and the uppercase `i` is:

```
-i (lowercase) Install the package
-I (uppercase) Show information about the package.
```

For other details see:

```
$ man dpkg
```

Comment: If you get an error about dependency problems, https://askubuntu.com/questions/40011/how-to-let-dpkg-i-install-dependencies-for-me fixed it for me.

Answer (score -1):

In Ubuntu Xenial (16.04) you can simply install with `apt`:

```
sudo apt install google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

Comment: You can in 16.04, try it.

Comment: Good to know because the [manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/apt.8.html) doesn't say anything about it and it definitely doesn't work in 14.04. I edited your answer to clarify that and so that I'm allowed to convert my previous down-vote.

Comment: This is wrong. You can't install Chrome from Ubuntu repos. This command works after you add the `dl.google.com...` source.

Comment: This command installs the downloaded google-chrome package. Not from the repositories! In 16.04 you can install downloaded .deb packages directly through apt. I just assumed the downloaded package is in the home directory, if in another place it can be something like this sudo apt install /home/user/Downloads/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb

Comment: You dont need the command line at all, download the package from the website, click(double) on it and when asked where to open it (if you have not previously associated .deb files) then select ubuntu software you will then be shown the gui to install it.

Comment: @AleksandrKaprizkin Your command won't work.  You try it.  The `apt` command doesn't take a `.deb` as an argument.  It only takes **package names** that are arguments.  You can check the available package names by running `apt search "packagename"`.  After installing the downloaded **google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb** package the **google-chrome-stable** becomes available in your apt package cache.  You might consider removing or revising your answer.  The way it is, it doesn't work at all and doesn't have any value to the question.

Comment: By the way, I'll remove my downvote if you revised to include something that could work or have some contribution to the question.