# Not able to launch TeamViewer

Tags: uninstall, reinstall, teamviewer

I am not able to launch TeamViewer in Ubuntu 16.04. I am wondering how to remove and install again. Any help on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TeamViewer is usually installed on Ubuntu [using *.deb package](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/linux/). To uninstall it, run:

```
sudo apt remove teamviewer
```

If you also want to remove the package’s configuration (and you likely want if you are experiencing problems), use the following command instead:

```
sudo apt purge teamviewer
```

Then [reinstall the *.deb file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40011/how-to-let-dpkg-i-install-dependencies-for-me) using `apt`, `gdebi` or similar method.

However, reinstalling might not solve your issue. If it doesn’t, please [ask a new question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) and provide more details like what happens when you try to launch it. Try launching from the Terminal and check if any messages appear in the Terminal.

Comment: Thanks. Now I find and able to launch Team Viewer. Is it possible to login and access ubuntu machine from windows 10 machine ?

Comment: Yes, I will accept your answer. I was looking for it how to click answered or accept. Do you have any idea about "to login and access ubuntu machine from windows 10 machine ?"

Comment: @engr_john I am not sure… If you have a new question, please [ask it separately](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). Don’t forget to add details (e.g. are the machines in the same network?). This is the way how this site works.