# Cant install aurees git client on Ubuntu 19.10: Dependencies not resolved

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, deb, git

I want to install the [Aurees](https://aurees.com/) GUI client on Xubuntu 19.10. Since I can't find a way to install it by repo, I downloaded the `.deb` file and tried to install it using [apt](https://askubuntu.com/a/795048/650986):

```
# LANG=en_US.utf8 apt install /home/user/Downloads/AureesSetup-linux.deb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'aureesgit' instead of '/home/user/Downloads/AureesSetup-linux.deb'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 aureesgit : PreDepends: libgconf2-4 but it is not installable
             PreDepends: libcurl3 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

In the *classic way* using `dpkg`

```
# LANG=en_US.utf8 dpkg -i /home/user/Downloads/AureesSetup-linux.deb
dpkg: regarding .../AureesSetup-linux.deb containing aureesgit, pre-dependency problem:
 aureesgit pre-depends on gtk-sharp2
  gtk-sharp2 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing archive /home/user/Downloads/AureesSetup-linux.deb (--install):
 pre-dependency problem - not installing aureesgit
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /home/user/Downloads/AureesSetup-linux.deb
```

But `apt-get install -f` doesn't fix the missing dependencies:

```
# LANG=en_US.utf8 apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

I also tried to fix the dependency problem by installing it manually:

```
apt install gtk-sharp2
```

This changes the error message to another package name, that is missing. So I don't think that this is a reliable way to fix the problem since I'd need to install every dependency manually.

Why is `apt` using a virtual package `aureesgit` and not able to resolve the dependencies? I installed other `deb` packages several times over the years and it worked well before

Answer (score 4):

This package requires dependencies from older Ubuntu release.

Installing these dependencies manually will not work because of downgrades of core system packages.

I would suggest you to contact the developer about supporting Ubuntu 19.10 and upcoming 20.04 LTS.