# Errors were encountered while processing: teamviewer

Tags: package-management, dpkg, 20.04

I tried to execute a **.deb** file and got the above error.

I just used `sudo dpkg -i teamviewer_15.5.3_amd64.deb` in my `Downloads` directory where the **.deb** file was located. I have dpkg `version 1.19.7 (amd64)` in my machine.

Here's what I'm getting:

```js
(Reading database ... 230272 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack teamviewer_15.5.3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking teamviewer (15.5.3) over (15.5.3) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of teamviewer:
 teamviewer depends on libqt5qml5 (>= 5.5) | qt56-teamviewer; however:
  Package libqt5qml5 is not installed.
  Package qt56-teamviewer is not installed.
 teamviewer depends on libqt5quick5 (>= 5.5) | qt56-teamviewer; however:
  Package libqt5quick5 is not installed.
  Package qt56-teamviewer is not installed.
 teamviewer depends on libqt5webkit5 (>= 5.5) | qt56-teamviewer; however:
  Package libqt5webkit5 is not installed.
  Package qt56-teamviewer is not installed.
 teamviewer depends on libqt5x11extras5 (>= 5.5) | qt56-teamviewer; however:
  Package libqt5x11extras5 is not installed.
  Package qt56-teamviewer is not installed.
 teamviewer depends on qml-module-qtquick2 (>= 5.5) | qt56-teamviewer; however:
  Package qml-module-qtquick2 is not installed.
  Package qt56-teamviewer is not installed.
 teamviewer depends on qml-module-qtquick-controls (>= 5.5) | qt56-teamviewer; however:
  Package qml-module-qtquick-controls is not installed.
  Package qt56-teamviewer is not installed.
 teamviewer depends on qml-module-qtquick-dialogs (>= 5.5) | qt56-teamviewer; however:
  Package qml-module-qtquick-dialogs is not installed.
  Package qt56-teamviewer is not installed.
 teamviewer depends on qml-module-qtquick-window2 (>= 5.5) | qt56-teamviewer; however:
  Package qml-module-qtquick-window2 is not installed.
  Package qt56-teamviewer is not installed.
 teamviewer depends on qml-module-qtquick-layouts (>= 5.5) | qt56-teamviewer; however:
  Package qml-module-qtquick-layouts is not installed.
  Package qt56-teamviewer is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package teamviewer (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.24-1ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.64ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 teamviewer
```

Comment: You are missing the listed dependencies. Use `sudo apt-get install -f` to install them. More information in this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/40011/how-to-let-dpkg-i-install-dependencies-for-me

Comment: Thanks, it ran. Btw, do we always have to use `sudo apt-get install -f` or is it just for the case of missing dependencies?

Comment: Just for the case of missing dependencies

Comment: Usually when you download third party packages from the Internet in `.deb` format, the `deb` file doesn't contain all the dependencies (and you wouldn't want it to either). Package managers often rely on `install -f` to sort it out.

Comment: Thanks for the info, @Jos.