# how do i install an older version of Audacity?

Tags: software-installation, source-code, audacity

I need to install an older version of Audacity because of the Chain Function.
I have no idear how to install it from the source files that are the only ones I can find.

Answer (score 3):

The safest way to install an older version of Audacity is to download its .deb file from [Ubuntu Packages Search](https://packages.ubuntu.com/) or from an official Ubuntu Launchpad website. You can select the version of Audacity from a list of Audacity versions at [Audacity in Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/audacity).

**Don't try to immediately install this .deb file!** Before you install the .deb file that you downloaded simulate the installation in order to check if there are any unmet dependencies with the following command.

```
apt install --simulate ./package-name.deb # This command does not require sudo.
```

where `package-name.deb` should be replaced by the name of a .deb file located in the current directory that you are trying to install.

If the command shows additional unmet dependencies then refer to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1023248) for information about how to manually download and install them. If the above command is successful then run the following command to install the older version Audacity .deb file that you downloaded.

```
sudo apt install ./package-name.deb
```

Answer (score 2):

Expand the Ubuntu versions and find the Audacity version you're looking for, follow the link to the .deb file.

https://pkgs.org/download/audacity

You may end up in dependency-hell and unable to install older versions easily.

Comment: It is always better to use official https://packages.ubuntu.com as package source.