# installing open3d on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dpkg, dependencies

I want to install Open3D on Ubuntu 20.04 but I get the following errors. How could I fix it?

```
mona@goku:~$ wget https://github.com/intel-isl/Open3D/releases/download/v0.12.0/open3d-app-0.12.0-Ubuntu_20.04.deb
--2021-01-28 19:03:24--  https://github.com/intel-isl/Open3D/releases/download/v0.12.0/open3d-app-0.12.0-Ubuntu_20.04.deb
Resolving github.com (github.com)... 140.82.113.4
Connecting to github.com (github.com)|140.82.113.4|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: https://github-releases.githubusercontent.com/75413130/8cd1a380-4e88-11eb-9639-e33b0a383434?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIWNJYAX4CSVEH53A%2F20210129%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20210129T000324Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=5f04a7b6d5eee8340ea6f3ebaf8fb2ac5a949d2e1bbfba71bcac6a3eea365a11&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&actor_id=0&key_id=0&repo_id=75413130&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3Dopen3d-app-0.12.0-Ubuntu_20.04.deb&response-content-type=application%2Foctet-stream [following]
--2021-01-28 19:03:24--  https://github-releases.githubusercontent.com/75413130/8cd1a380-4e88-11eb-9639-e33b0a383434?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIWNJYAX4CSVEH53A%2F20210129%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20210129T000324Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=5f04a7b6d5eee8340ea6f3ebaf8fb2ac5a949d2e1bbfba71bcac6a3eea365a11&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&actor_id=0&key_id=0&repo_id=75413130&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3Dopen3d-app-0.12.0-Ubuntu_20.04.deb&response-content-type=application%2Foctet-stream
Resolving github-releases.githubusercontent.com (github-releases.githubusercontent.com)... 185.199.110.154, 185.199.111.154, 185.199.108.154, ...
Connecting to github-releases.githubusercontent.com (github-releases.githubusercontent.com)|185.199.110.154|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 110120788 (105M) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘open3d-app-0.12.0-Ubuntu_20.04.deb’

open3d-app-0.12.0-Ubuntu_20.04.d 100%[=========================================================>] 105.02M  5.11MB/s    in 22s     

2021-01-28 19:03:47 (4.74 MB/s) - ‘open3d-app-0.12.0-Ubuntu_20.04.deb’ saved [110120788/110120788]

mona@goku:~$ sudo dpkg -i open3d-app-0.12.0-Ubuntu_20.04.deb
[sudo] password for mona: 
Selecting previously unselected package open3d-viewer.
(Reading database ... 408548 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack open3d-app-0.12.0-Ubuntu_20.04.deb ...
Unpacking open3d-viewer (0.12.0) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of open3d-viewer:
 open3d-viewer depends on libc++1; however:
  Package libc++1 is not installed.
 open3d-viewer depends on libglfw3; however:
  Package libglfw3 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package open3d-viewer (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.24-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.64ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.15-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 open3d-viewer
mona@goku:~$ sudo apt install libc++1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc++1 : Depends: libc++1-10 (>= 10~) but it is not going to be installed
 libopencv-highgui2.4v5 : Depends: libpng12-0 (>= 1.2.13-4) but it is not going to be installed
 open3d-viewer : Depends: libglfw3 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
mona@goku:~$ sudo apt --fix-broken install libc++1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc++1 : Depends: libc++1-10 (>= 10~) but it is not going to be installed
 libopencv-highgui2.4v5 : Depends: libpng12-0 (>= 1.2.13-4) but it is not going to be installed
 open3d-viewer : Depends: libglfw3 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: Please add the output of `apt-cache policy libc++1 libc++1-10 libopencv-highgui2.4v5  libglfw3` to the question.

Comment: @karel It is deep third-party repository problem, please reopen to get this particular problem fixed.

Comment: There is a [duplicate](https://askubuntu.com/a/1023248/) of Norbert's answer to this question in the linked duplicate question.

Comment: @karel It is duplicate only in case of fresh installation. This means without 3rd party repositories.

Comment: Marking duplicate is fast, but not effective. Please reopen.

Comment: @N0rbert Instead of reopening the question I added another link to account for the possibility you mentioned in your comment. Obviously neither you or I can test for the case of all possible 3rd party repositories.

Comment: At first we need additional info from OP. Closing is too early.

Comment: If I see incontrovertible evidence from the question's author that this question is insoluble by the aforementioned means then I will reopen it. Were it not for the possibility of package management errors that were caused by 3rd party repositories this .deb file could be installed by a one-liner apt command in 20.04 without any additional commands.

Comment: @N0rbert https://pastebin.com/raw/ddw4SzZU

Comment: solution: https://askubuntu.com/a/1312140/165324

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On fresh Ubuntu 20.04 LTS system without third-party repositories you have to install this package using apt to get dependencies resolved:

```
wget -c https://github.com/intel-isl/Open3D/releases/download/v0.12.0/open3d-app-0.12.0-Ubuntu_20.04.deb
sudo apt-get install ./open3d-app-0.12.0-Ubuntu_20.04.deb
```

The above package set will not require `libpng12`.

In your current situation you have to give additional information about used dependencies.